# Locale specific lowercase/uppercase string manipulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, locale, uppercase

How can we entertain locale specific strings/character uppercase and lowercase manipulations in JavaScript?
Like for example, Java provides **java.lang.Character** class for locale specific manipulations and the some of the methods are as follows:

- **toUpperCase(char ch)** --> converts a unicode character to uppercase
- **toLowerCase(char ch)** --> converts a unicode character to lowercase

  (the language specific uppercase/lowercase is handled automatically)

Similarly,

- **isUpperCase(char ch)**
- **isLowerCase(char ch)**

are also available.

The coding example is as follows:

```
    /*This is a greek character*/
    ch='\u03B4';
    System.out.println(ch);
    System.out.println("Is Character = "+ Character.isLetter(ch));
    System.out.println("Is Digit = " + Character.isDigit(ch));
    System.out.println("Upper case = " + Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    System.out.println();
```

Its output is as follows:

```
    δ
    Is Character = true
    Is Digit = false
    Upper case = Δ
```

See, the uppercase character is entirely different from the lowercase character. Now, if we want this functionality in JavaScript, do we any way?

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: What do you mean? `'δ'.toUpperCase() === 'Δ'`.

Comment: This isn't really locale specific case manipulation. This is trivial compared with, for example, `"i".toUpperCase()` which normally results in `"I"` in most languages, except Turkish where the correct result should be a dotted capital I: `"İ"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, following works like a charm in javascript (tested in Firebug console in Firefox 6):

```
ch='\u03B4'; // δ
ch_up = ch.toUpperCase() //ch_up is now: "Δ"
ch_down = ch_up.toLowerCase() // ch_down is now "δ"
```

Comment: In the meanwhile, I myself discovered that toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() are basically UNICODE AWARE.